# Responsive SPA prevent mobile nav bar to autohide

Tags: reactjs, uinavigationbar, responsive

I have a fully functionnal SPA website (Reactjs) which I just made responsive. Everything went smooth except that the site refuses any "scroll movement" on the body, preventing the mobile browser bottom bar to disappear. It is a one page website which I created to have everything displayed full-screen (no need to scroll anything), so I suppose that it is CSS linked, but I just have absolutely no clue on what is happening. Actually, on my Samsung S20+, only the opened burger menu accepts any page scroll movement, permitting me to hide those navigator bars (up and bottom). But once again, I see no specific CSS differences between that burger menu and the main page. Could anyone help me on this ? I'm so lost with it that I don't even know what kind of information I could add in this post except the URL of the website: https://www.epistolads.net.

NB: the sources maps are available on the website, for testing purpose

EDIT 1: just noticed that I can achieve the desired result (scroll on page to hide nav bar) by first zooming a little, if it speaks to anyone.

EDIT 2: Also, I may no "refresh the website" by scrolling "out of screen" up.

Answer (score 0):

Ho mine, got it ! Some month ago, to be sure that no forgotten content gets out of the screen, I added a "overflow-y: hidden;" on the body of the index.html file itself! Changing it back to "auto" gave me back full control on mobile. In case of other people would meet the same problem...